# Amazon S3 subdomain to /directory with apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

On my VPS I have a subdomain and it is image.example.com. And this subdomain actually is an Amazon S3 bucket which is pointed with CNAME record.

See, how it works from AWS doc: (Go to *To associate a host name with an Amazon S3 bucket using CNAMEs* section)

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html

How to 301 redirect an Amazon bucket which works with CNAME like `images.example.com/myimage.jpg` to `example.com/images/myimage.jpg`

I tried this;

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^images\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images(/|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ images/$1 [L]
```

But I'm getting 500 - Internal server error

Clearly I want to redirect a subdomain to directory which this subdomain actually works for S3 bucket and pointed with CNAME

Comment: Please clarify *"redirect a bucket."*  You want to redirect requests from your web server *to* the bucket?  Or redirect requests from the bucket to the web server?  Or stop using the bucket and let your web server handle the images by adding `/images` to the request path? It's difficult to determine what you are actually trying to accomplish.  To avoid suboptimal solutions or an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), we need to understand, specifically, what you are *really* trying to accomplish, not just how you are currently trying to accompish it.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot see updated ver. of my question please